# Removing parameters from url using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello stackoverflow community. I need ideas and help. Is it possible to remove that pagination from link? for example: http://example.com/comp-filter/page/2/ So i need to remove that page/2/ and i do not know how, because that number can be from 1 to eternity. So what could i do to remove it using jquery or javascript. Help please? For replacing parameters i was using:

```
function setGetParameter(paramName, paramValue)
{
    var url = window.location.href;
    if (url.indexOf(paramName + "=") >= 0)
    {
        var prefix = url.substring(0, url.indexOf(paramName));
        var suffix = url.substring(url.indexOf(paramName));
        suffix = suffix.substring(suffix.indexOf("=") + 1);
        suffix = (suffix.indexOf("&") >= 0) ? suffix.substring(suffix.indexOf("&")) : "";
        url = prefix + paramName + "=" + paramValue + suffix;
    }
    else
    {
    if (url.indexOf("?") < 0)
        url += "?" + paramName + "=" + paramValue;
    else
        url += "&" + paramName + "=" + paramValue;
    }
    return url;
}
```

But chaning this code wont help...

Comment: Can you use a regular expression?

Comment: jQuery **is** JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5's [history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method) is what you're looking for.

What you want to do is `replaceState`.

> history.replaceState() operates exactly like history.pushState() except that replaceState() modifies the current history entry instead of creating a new one.

So, your code would be smth like:

```
history.replaceState(data, document.title, newUrl);
```

For actual replacement you should try regular expressions:

```
oldUrl.replace(/page\/\d+\/?/, '');
```

Best regards, Alexander